# Dynamically Change the href path of image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jquery-plugins

I am not sure is possible or not but someone know suggest me if possible.

For example:

```
<a href="image/image.jpg"><img src="image/image.jpg" alt="image"/></a>
```

in this how to change the href path to another image dynamically using jquery. 
i.e.,

```
<a href="image/img.jpg"><img src="image/image.jpg" alt="image"/></a> like this.
```

**EDITED:**
If

```
<a href="#"><img src="image/image.jpg"/></a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><img src="image/image.jpg"/></a>
<a href="image/image.jpg"><img src="image/image.jpg"/></a>
```

How can i vary this `href attr` that condition should satisfy only when the anchor tag of href link contain image. then the anchor text is should `img` tag.

**Here is the JSFIDDLE:**
[http://jsfiddle.net/HMsSE/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/HMsSE/2/)
Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
vicky

Comment: do you want to change it by click or simply on load?

Comment: By click the image it should be change the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can try using `.prop()`

```
$('a').prop('href', 'image/img.jpg')
```

From your comments, you're trying to change the `href` of `a` tag when it has a child element `img`.  If so,

```
if($('a').find('img').length) {  // it return the no. of img tag within a
   $('a').prop('href', 'image/img.jpg');
}
```

Comment: @vicky you can use `.find()` like this `if( $('a').find('img').length )`

Comment: Thanks for your Response. sorry for asking multi question. That above code is for anchor tag with child as img also is possible to check anchor tag with href as image src then child as img tag

Comment: For example : <a href="#"><img="img/image.jpg"/></a> in this condition if # or anyother link then that condition won't do

Comment: @vicky If I understood your question properly then possible.  You want to check the `if( href of a is img src &&  $('a').find('img').length)`.  Correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: @vicky ok I understood your question.  we can have a condition like this `if($('a').attr('href').indexOf('.jpg') > 0)`

Comment: Awesome Final Question how to check for png or gif otherformat See Here is the fiddle that i tried http://jsfiddle.net/HMsSE/2/

Comment: @vicky you can use this `var ext = $('a').attr('href').split('.').pop();
console.log(ext);` to get the ext of the href.

Comment: @user1671639 you cahnge `href` of all `<a>` elements on the page!

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to set the href to the new value:

```
$('a[href="image/image.jpg"]').attr('href', 'image/img.jpg');
```

Of course it probably would be easier if you give the anchor an unique id:

```
<a href="image/image.jpg" id="myLink"><img src="image/image.jpg" alt="image"/></a>
```

So that you could more easily select it:

```
$('#myLink').attr('href', 'image/img.jpg');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. That changing the href path only if the <img> tag present how can i do this

Comment: The same way: `$('img[src="image/image.jpg"]').attr('src', 'image/img.jpg');`.

Comment: Thanks. I need to explain detail. checking the condition if the anchor text contain <img> tag then only it should perform.? is it possible

Comment: Yes, you could give your img an unique id as shown in my answer and then make an id selector: `$('#myImage')`.

Comment: It only possible by unique id. I want to perform it dynamically. Using the image tag

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically? What if you have multiple `<img>` elements? You want to replace all their `src` properties? If so then you could simply use `$('img').attr(...)`. But once again this will replace ALL the images.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function

```
$('a').attr('href','image/img.jpg');
```

You can change it also by id which would be more useful

```
<a id="myLink" href="image/image.jpg"><img src="image/image.jpg" alt="image"/></a>

$('#myLink').attr('href','image/img.jpg');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, How can i check if the anchor text contain image tag

Answer (score 2):

as topicstarter aksed, change performs on image click

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('a').attr("href","image/img.jpg");
});
```

if you want to check href too, you have to use a condition

```
$('a').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).attr('href').search('jpg')!=-1)
        $(this).attr("href","image/img.jpg");
});
```

also, I have to mention that `<img>` inside `<a>` is not always responsive for click

oh yeah, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/yhfRk/)
**UPD** I don't know how could I forget about filter

```
$('a').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).filter('[href*=jpg],[href*=png],[href*=gif]').attr("href","image/img.jpg");
});
```

[new shorter demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/yhfRk/3/)

Comment: @vicky no problem, [here we are](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/yhfRk/), but my code also must be a little bit updated

Comment: Thanks How to check if the png or jpg or gif accordingly

Comment: @vicky just use search('jpg|png|gif') instead

Comment: Thanks for your response, but in your fiddle itself third image path is to anchor tag href image/image.jpg and is not coming image/img.jpg

Comment: @vicky maybe I don't understand you, are you [sure](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/yhfRk/2/) it doesn't change?

Comment: No still i didn't get any alert too. . .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32914/discussion-between-vladkras-and-vicky)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in native Javascript without including jQuery

> element.setAttribute(attributename,attributevalue)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I think it should be like `document.getElementsByTagName("tagName").setAttribute("attributename","attributevalue")`

Comment: I wrote a general syntax. You specify getElementByTagName. Developer might use more ways to get element like Id or so.